# Hide the URL in the in the adressbar and show another URL

Tags: php

I am using different pages on my website. I want to hide the URL in the adressbar for the users.

I have pages like:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/system/index.php
www.example.com/system/pages/page1/index.php
```

I want to hide the URLs like `www.example.com/system/pages/page1/index.php` and show in the addressbar a URL like `http://system.example.com`

How can I do this?

Edit 1:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dirname/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^dirname/)^(.*)$ /system/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: While this may look better, I hope you realize how hard it will be to bookmark pages then.

Comment: So you want to set up one subdomain for each and every single page?

Comment: The pages that I want to 'hide' are the pages of a 'application'. I dont want that the users bookmark the pages of the application

Comment: No, I have 1 subdomain. The URL of this subdomain should be in the addressbar when the user is on a page with url like `www.example.com/system/pages/page1/index.php
`

Comment: You have to use htaccess :)

Comment: Look to the edit in my first post. This is what I am using in my htaccess. But I get a error when I open my website